# How do Java Timers act under duress?

Tags: java, timer, repeat, specifications

i have a simple timer that calls a method to do background processing every minute.  It is called like this:

```
EmailSender singletonSender = new EmailSender(cog);
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(singletonSender, 60000, 60000);
```

Every minute it receives an event, checks to see if there is any reason to send email, sends the email, and then it is done.

This all assumes that the system is up and running, and that there is available CPU cycles.  If the computer is sitting there doing nothing else, and the handling takes no time, it is all very easy to understand.  But I can't find documentation on how this behaves when the computer is excessively busy, or when it is put into sleep/hybernation mode.

**What happens if the computer is put asleep?**

After a examining many confusing logs, I finally ran a test.  Had it print out a log statement and the current time.  I put the computer to sleep at 7:30 (about) and woke it up 10 minutes later (about).  Here is the log trace:

```
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:24:28
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:25:28
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:26:28
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:27:28
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:28:28
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:29:28
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:30:28
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:31:28
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:40:09
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:40:09
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:40:09
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:40:09
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:40:09
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:40:09
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:40:09
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:40:09
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:40:28
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:41:28
BACKGROUND EVENTS: Processed 0 background events at Fri Nov 06 07:42:28
```

It appears to send a bunch of "catch up" events.  In other words, it is as if they are piling up in the computer while it is asleep, and then they all flood out once the machine is reactivated.  It is as if all the events were generated, but held up by the inability to deliver them, and finally, when the computer started, all of them flood out.

Is this documented as designed to work this way?  Clearly this has an effect on how you design your system.  IT is logical that if you are expecting 1440 events per day, you will ultimately get 1440 events.  However, if you are just doing background processing, and each call gets all the waiting background stuff done, then those extra calls are kind of meaningless.  You will want to design the method to handle those extra flood of calls very quickly.

**What if it takes more than a minute to respond to the call?**

Given the evidence above, it would appear that if the computer gets very busy, it might be possible that your event is sent late, but you will still get all the events.  So if the processing of an event takes more than a minute, the question is: can you be assured that the event will not arrive on a different thread?  On other words:  are you assured that your handler will never be called before the last call is finished.  The Timer mechanism attempt to hide details about what thread you are called on, and it seems reasonable to assume that all the calls are made on a single thread, however, again, I am looking for clear documentation on this.

What I am wondering: is this strictly defined some place?  Or just an artifact of the way that the current version is implemented?

Comment: You may want to try with a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to see if it behaves the same. Also an alternative to scheduleAtFixedRate is to schedule a new run at the end of each run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least the Javadocs of [`Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long)) suggest what you observed:

> In fixed-rate execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the scheduled execution time of the initial execution. **If an execution is delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background activity), two or more executions will occur in rapid succession to "catch up."** In the long run, the frequency of execution will be exactly the reciprocal of the specified period (assuming the system clock underlying Object.wait(long) is accurate).

Comment: Thanks for finding that,  that answers the first question.  I re-worded the second question to clarify that essentially I am wondering if this is designed to be single threaded.  I suspect it is, but not sure.

Comment: Ok, found the other answer in the java doc (gee that was difficult :-) so marking this as the accepted answer.